# Set width of table cell relative to other cell in column

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

Here is the basic setup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="short">A medium width cell.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="long" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">A long long long long long long cell.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(See also http://jsfiddle.net/vp1rzrnt/.)

I would like to achieve that the `#long` cell in the second table row does not expand in it's width over the `#short` cell and is just cut off.

Unfortunately, just setting `overflow: hidden` as I did does not do the trick.

#### Edit

And I cannot set a fixed width, since the content is dynamic.

#### Edit 2

Ideally, I would like to be able to still use the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` feature to signal the cutting.

Comment: Are you ok with a single line jQuery solution?

Comment: Never used jQuery. But I guess I can rewrite it in JavaScript. However, ideally I would like to rely on css only... But that may be impossible. That said: I am happy for any solution.

Comment: I've put both, jQuery and js solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only **css** solution.

Mixture of both [GCyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/gcyrillus) [[Soln]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216406/3603806) and my[[Soln]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216400/3603806) previous solutions.

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vp1rzrnt/8/

**UPDATE :**

```
td {
    border: solid;
    display:block;
}
#short, #long {
    width:100%;
}
#long {
    margin-right:-1000px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

**html** : without additional tags

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="short">A medium width cell.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="long">A long long long long long long cell.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need the additional HTML tags and IDs within the `td` if you set the `td` to `display: block`

Comment: Seems perfect for me! Thanks.

Comment: @thecbuilder: Now there is extra space on the right side of the cell. I do not know where it came from, but I preferred the version with the `p` tag to the one without.

Comment: #did you add `width:100%` to both `#long` and `#short` as in the new css?

Answer (score 2):

With a wrapper for td content, you may virtually reduce its width.**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vp1rzrnt/1/)**

HTML wrapped

```
<td id="long" style="overflow: hidden;"><p>A long long long long long long cell.</p></td>
```

CSS

```
tr + tr td p{
    margin:0;
    margin-right:-1000px;/* hudge negative margin to reduce virtually width to  nothing*/
}
```

overflowing content won't be reachable :(

Comment: Nice trick. Unfortunately, I see now that working with overflow was more important for me than I realized. For example, I would like to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. If I see it correctly, this feature is also lost with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick jQuery Solution : http://jsfiddle.net/vp1rzrnt/3/

```
$(function(){$("#long").width($("#short span").width());});
```

Similar thing in js : http://jsfiddle.net/vp1rzrnt/2/

```
long.style.width = s_span.offsetWidth + "px";
```

A lil change in html : (added `<span>`)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="short"><span id="s_span">A medium width cell.</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="long">A long long long long long long cell.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

FOR `text-overflow:ellipsis;` :  http://jsfiddle.net/vp1rzrnt/5/

**html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="short"><span id="s_span">A medium width cell.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="long">
            <p id="long_p">A long long long long long long cell.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
td {
    border: solid;
}
#long_p {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#long_p").width($("#s_span").width());
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately the text is not "just cut off", but gets broken into new lines. Also, some nice css features, e.g. `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, get lost with this solution.

Comment: Great! This seems to do the trick. I guess I will have to rely on JS to make this work. This task seems a but too tricky for pure CSS, although the with should just stay the way it is with no content in the cell...